Replicate asp-for functionality on any element
ASP.NET Core's <input> and <label> tag helpers support the asp-for property, which generates id, name and for appropriately.
Is it possible to get those values somehow and use them on some other element?
For example, this:
<input asp-for=@Model.User.Name />
<div asp-for@Model.User.Name=>Foo</div>

Renders this:
<input id="User_Name" name="User.Name" ... />
<div asp-for=@Model.User.Name>Foo</div>

Obviously the asp-for won't work on the div, but I'd like to do something like that. Is that possible?
(Currently I either hardcode the values or use some kludge involving multiple nameof calls. I prefer a dynamic solution that works similarly to asp-for.)

there are various HtmlHelper methods available.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

@browsermator I forgot all about those helper methods... haven't used them since ASP.NET (pre-Core) almost ten years ago. Thanks! If you add that as an answer I'll close. What worked for me: for="@(Html.IdFor(x => x.User.Name))".

you can add your own answer to close... that way you can include the full use-case.

@browsermator Ok, but I didn't want to steal your thunder. :-) I added an answer below. Thanks again!

Thanks to the comment by @browsermator, this is possible using IHtmlHelper<TModel>.
Those were an important part of ASP.NET almost ten years ago - i.e. before ASP.NET Core - so I forgot about them completely. They are still available.
Suppose I have an input, and want to reference it (via JavaScript) from some related element:
<input asp-for=@Model.User.Name ... />
<div for="@(Html.IdFor(x => x.User.Name))">Foo</div>

That renders:
<input id="User_Name" name="User.Name" ... />
<div for="User_Name">Foo</div>

One could also use Html.NameFor or whatever else is appropriate.
